# no R.java in gen folder - android

Tags: android, eclipse

I know there are a lot of questions similar to this one. But I have tried the solutions and none are working. I thought one of the following should work:
1. Getting rid of 'import android.R' line.
2. Cleaning the project and then building it again.

Still I have the same old "R cannot be resolved to a variable" problem. The gen folder is empty.

Comment: is there any error in project or any error in Problems view (Windows->vies->Problems)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usually means that you have a problem with one of your resources so R cannot be generated. Check the layout XMLs and see if one of them have a warning / error.

After removing the error please clean the project Project->clean

Comment: There was a small error in one of the xml files. I corrected it and now there is R.java in gen folder. But the error is still there.

Comment: What do you mean the error is still there? have you tried clean / rebuild after you fixed the error?

Comment: Got it fixed! There was a small change in the package name in the manifest file. It was not flagged as an eror, so I missed it. After I fixed that, done the clean/build, it worked. Thanx for ur help.

Answer (score 6):

I've had a similar issue some days ago. My R.java was not regenerated after I cleaned my project.
Here is what fixed it for me: It seems like as of SDK version 22, which I had recently downloaded, there is an additional package you have to download from the SDK manager called "**Android SDK build-tools**". Without this package, Eclipse will not generate R.
I installed it, restarted Eclipse and everything was working again.
I had found the solution on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16643060/1691231

Comment: you saved my life, i just started to get too angry

Answer (score 2):

This may occur because of your project has errors, Please try to **clear the errors**, **remove 'import android.R**' line and **Clean and build** the Project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

at first fix your layout errors.

then go to menu project-> clean and select your project

Answer (score 0):

This also generally means something wrong with the build process...Have a look at the libraries tab under Java Build Path option in project properties dialog.....

Answer (score 0):

Check your XML resources (especially these recently edited) for mistakes and sytax errors. When you have an error inside one of these files, the R class autogeneration will abort.