# Eclipse error: R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting this classic error in Eclipse IDE. I am bored of Eclipse's bugs. They driving me mad.

I almost tried everything which suggested as solution (by Googling). None of them worked.

My project was working normally but not code changes.

I see that my code changes does not acting on my app (on AVD) then I cleaned my project (under `Project > Clean...`). `R.java` file was gone and res folder was empty.

Now I am getting that error: `R cannot be resolved to a variable.`

What should I do?

And also I tried to delete project and create again with `Android Project from Existing Code` I've backed-up before. It already gives same error after cleaning.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check your res/values folder is there any error ?

Comment: Can you post the imports for the Class that is giving you issues?

Comment: @user1911784 No, there is no error there.

Comment: @daniel_c05 This import giving the error: "import com.<app_name>.app.R;" Sorry to hide app name.

Comment: Have you tried unchecking "Build Automatically". Then clean without rebuilding. Then "Build Project". At any point keep checking the "Problems" view (Windows -> Show Views -> Other -> Problems) for anything that is not "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Have you updated your ADT with version 22?

Comment: The R.java is not generated when you have some sort of error in nay of your xml files. Check your xml file for errors, or a "." where it should not supposed to be or anything like that.

Comment: @J.Romero When I clean without rebuilding, errors disappeared. But then build project, they appeared again.

Comment: @PareshMayani Yes, I updated. Maybe, it occurs the error. I don't know.

Comment: Hope my G+ post helps you out. Check: https://plus.google.com/u/0/101756163023567589496/posts/TWTi1w63Zdg

Comment: @JustWork Did you check the Problems view for anything other than "R cannot be resolved to a variable" it would tell you what is actually preventing it from generating the R.java file.

Comment: @J.Romero I have errors in 73 items in there. But none of them different than "R cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: I noted that using an old workspace gave me this problem, even after installing the new build tools. When I created a completely new workspace for my Android projects the issue dissapered.

Comment: SO moderators please don't mark such questions as duplicate. Eclipse, Xcode keep on changing every year and old solutions don't work anymore. Perhaps SO can suggest the latest similar questions so that many people wouldn't have to trawl old questions for hours before stumbling across the latest one.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

I assume you have updated ADT with version 22 and R.java file is not getting generated.

If this is the case, then here is the solution:

Hope you know Android studio has gradle building tool. Same as in eclipse they have given new component in the Tools folder called Android SDK Build-tools that needs to be installed. Open the Android SDK Manager, select the newly added build tools, install it, restart the SDK Manager after the update.

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion didn't solve my problem. Only changing of target API to 19 in project -> properties -> Adroid -> Project Build Target did provide the solution.

Answer (score 17):

I'm not posting this as an answer but a confirmation to Paresh's accepted answer. I recently updated SDK tools to Revision 22 and I noticed my code changes was not being affective on the device i'm testing at all. Such as the url I was using, I was getting errors for connection time out regarding the url I was "previously" using. Therefore I cleaned the project and built again only to find out that autogenerated R.java file is missing.

After reading Paresh's answer and checking what's going on with my sdk manager this is what I saw:
[image]

SDK Build-tools 17 was not installed and there was already a new update to SDK tools even though it does not mention any change related to this problem in the changelog, this update brought back my R.java file and the related problems were gone after an eclipse restart and final clean/rebuild on the project.

Comment: +1 Great words!! Cheers

Comment: This answer provides an important detail. Restart of Eclipse is a must. But restarting of SDK Manager (mentioned in another answer) was not helpful, and was not even necessary in my case.

Answer (score 9):

The R file can't be generated if your layout contains errors.  If your `res` folder is empty, then it's safe to assume that there's no `res/layout` folder with any layouts in it, but your activity is probably calling `setContentView` and not finding anything -- that qualifies as a problem with your layout.

Comment: How did you get that my res folder is empty? It is not empty and also res/layout is not empty and there are 9 xml files in it.

Comment: Quoted from your own post: "and res folder was empty."

Comment: Care about full sentence: "then I cleaned my project (under Project > Clean...). R.java file was gone and res folder was empty." It was empty after I cleaned. Such things happen. Thank you anyway.

Comment: The totality of the sentence was less than helpful without an indication somewhere that you recreated the res folder afterwards. Absolute clarity is the path to good answers, but I'm glad the issue is resolved for you.

Comment: Great solution to resolve this eclipse issue

Answer (score 4):

Try to delete the import line `import com.your.package.name.app.R`, then, any resource calls such as `mView= (View) mView.findViewById(R.id.resource_name);` will highlight the 'R' with an error, a 'Quick fix' will prompt you to import R, and there will be at least two options:

- android.R
- your.package.name.R

Select the R corresponding to your package name, and you should be good to go. Hope that helps.

Comment: I had already tried that but there is no "<my_package_name>.R" in Quick fix menu. There is just "android.R" there.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to install the build tools and restart the update manager I also had to restart Eclipse to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a fully working project to which I was doing a minor change when this occured after updateting the SDK.
Eclipse updated the SDK and the ADT but I could still not build the project. Exlipse said there were no further updates available.

The problem persisted until I manually uninstalled the ADT from eclipse and re-installed it. 
Only then would my project build. I had restarted eclipse inbetween each step.