# R file is not created

Tags: java, android

i am new to android i open a new project i try to run it  but it cant run because it says that R file is not created .i did not do anything to the project which i opened here . please help me to run this .

and also i got a sample project when i try to run that also it cant be run because it says that R file cannot be created also.

please what should i do to solve this help me please. and also i want to know that what is R file in it i try to edit that but it says R file cannot be modify why is that going on so

Comment: U need to refer library `appcompat_v7` will solve your problem

Comment: thank you how can i do that please give me the instructions which i needed to do

Comment: which android sdk you are using??

Comment: from my head, these constitute from a lot of things  could be xml errors or others, like @Rohit pointed out

Comment: check out these links and whiles you read and try to solve your problem you learn in the process, much healthier way to learn it.. [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating),[link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726544/android-r-file-not-generating),[link 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585528/android-adt-version-22-r-java-files-not-generated),[link 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721585/android-r-java-will-not-generate-in-eclipse), all these address your issue..

Comment: See when you create new project, `appcompat_v7` library gets imported automatically and it gets reffered automatically. If not then right click on your project->properties->android in library section Add then add the `appcompat_v7` library..

Comment: i installed appcompat_v7 and there are no errors in that folder but then other project can not run errors are still going on there

Comment: Check your resource file names for invalid characters. Only `a, ..., z` (lower case), `0, ..., 9` (not at beginning), `.` and `_` are allowed.