# R cannot be resolved after update to adt 22

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, updates

I have been away from using eclipse and android java programming for a few weeks due to unforseen circumstances. I opened up eclipse yesterday and was prompted to make a few updates and accepted. Now all of my programs/applications work and all are coming back with errors. Everything was fine when I left it a few weeks ago.

The main problem is R cannot be resolved to a variable but I have fixed that before in the past. Nothing seems to work, I have tried many solutions.

Is everyone having the same problem after updating to ADT 22 or is it just me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642604/eclipse-error-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable/16643060#16643060. check this

Comment: Download build tools from sdkmanager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open SDK Manager and download & install the Android SDK <s>Platform</s> Build-Tools Kit.