# "string cannot be resolved into a type"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Likewise, I cannot access many java.lang features in my Android ADT project.
Java *is* in my Build Path (or so I believe). In the Package Explorer, the JRE System Library clearly shows up.

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you see `JRE System Library [jre version]` in your `Package Ecplorer`? It should be under `src` OR `Referenced Libraries`. If `Yes` then you have java available in your build path.

Comment: @Smit, yeah its there like I said.

Comment: At any rate I moved to a different workspace and it seems to be fixed.

Comment: You mean you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Is it a case problem? String must have an upper-case 'S' and the title of this post show string with a lower-case 's'.

Comment: nop. It doesn't work with "String" as well. The headline is the result of me being used to C#.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Android SDK Manager and download the new Android SDK Build-Tools package. You may have to update your Android SDK Manager first in order to see this.

Screenshot here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16643060/1207921