# Error with R class import in android

Tags: java, android, class

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.connecttest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.example.bttest.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;

public class ConnectTest extends Activity {
  TextView out;
  private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
  private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
  private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
  private OutputStream outStream = null;

  // Well known SPP UUID
  private static final UUID MY_UUID =
      UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

  // Insert your server's MAC address
  private static String address = "00:00:00:00:00:00";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);

    out.append("\n...In onCreate()...");

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    CheckBTState();
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    out.append("\n...In onStart()...");
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    out.append("\n...In onResume...\n...Attempting client connect...");

    // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    // Two things are needed to make a connection:
    //   A MAC address, which we got above.
    //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
    //     UUID for SPP.
    try {
      btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      AlertBox("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
    // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
    try {
      btSocket.connect();
      out.append("\n...Connection established and data link opened...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      try {
        btSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException e2) {
        AlertBox("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
      }
    }

    // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
    out.append("\n...Sending message to server...");

    try {
      outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      AlertBox("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    String message = "Hello from Android.\n";
    byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
    try {
      outStream.write(msgBuffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
      if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00")) 
        msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 37 in the java code";
      msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";

      AlertBox("Fatal Error", msg);       
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    out.append("\n...In onPause()...");

    if (outStream != null) {
      try {
        outStream.flush();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        AlertBox("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
      }
    }

    try     {
      btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
      AlertBox("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    out.append("\n...In onStop()...");
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    out.append("\n...In onDestroy()...");
  }

  private void CheckBTState() {
    // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on

    // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
    if(btAdapter==null) { 
      AlertBox("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth Not supported. Aborting.");
    } else {
      if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        out.append("\n...Bluetooth is enabled...");
      } else {
        //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(btAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
      }
    }
  }

  public void AlertBox( String title, String message ){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle( title )
    .setMessage( message + " Press OK to exit." )
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
          finish();
        }
    }).show();
  }
}
```

This code has errors recurring every time the importing of R class comes up.

```
import com.example.bttest.R;
```

shows that the import cannot be resolved.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

and

```
out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);
```

shows that R cannot be resolved to a variable.

Please suggest something to get this working.

Comment: This is a very common problem in android. Have you tried Cleaning your project? Also - search for your error or have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable

Comment: Is your ADT version is 22? If yes then check: [Eclipse error: R cannot be resolved to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642604/eclipse-error-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable/16643060#16643060)

Comment: Yep! I tried cleaning and rebuilding my project, but still, the error persisted. And yes, my ADT version is 22.

Comment: when you clean your project you have error in your Android console.read this first

Comment: @RanveerAggarwal As you are having ADT 22, you need to check my above comment.

Comment: Try and press ctrl+shft+o i think this will work

Comment: ctrl+shift+o doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the "gen" folder in your project, clean and rebuild. R.java is generated automatically on build

Comment: Instead of generating R.java, it is generating BuildConfig.java

Comment: @RanveerAggarwal it should genarate both actually, Check wether you have errors in Manifest file or any res files

Comment: Yeah, you are right! My xml file indeed has an error, it says error parsing xml, mismatched tag.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>`

Comment: nice, means issue solved ?? i'd have written that comment as Answer atleast ! :(

Comment: Yeah! That's fine, but now this new error has come up, apparently without which I can't find out whether the previous issues have been resolved or not.

Comment: Nope! Not yet :(
Unable to resolve the new error.

Comment: whats the new error ?

Comment: It's in the xml file, check the third comment.

Comment: No wait! The error in the xml file got resolved. But still ,the previous error persists.

Comment: tried cleaning / restarting eclipse ?

Comment: project-properties is set to correct version and also make sure minSdkVersion in Manifest file is correct

Comment: if still not solved check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable

Comment: @CharanPai has given some good suggestions. One last suggestion is to make sure that eclipse ADT plugin and Android SDK version are the same. Different version sometimes cause strange problem. And also Clean, Rebuild and Refresh project and restart eclipse.