# No gen folder after SDK update (Windows 7, Eclipse Indigo)

Tags: android

I have a workspace with several projects in it.   For one of those projects I needed to upgrade the SDK to get the latest tools so I ran the installer_r22.0.1-windows.exe.   The installer ran without incident and reported **"Installation Complete. Setup was completed successfully"**

Now **none** of the projects in the workspace build, including perfectly good ones that build fine before this and haven't been changed in months.   In all of them the problem is the same:  no gen folder is created, so hundreds of "R cannot be resolved to a variable" errors appear.   There are no other errors reported.

I've restarted Eclipse.  All my builds are preceded by a clean.   How do I figure out what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642604/eclipse-error-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable/16643060#16643060. try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `android-sdk`, I think sdk need `Android SDK Build-tools`. For update it follow some steps-- **Go to Window->Android SDK Manager**. Update and Install all tools (`Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-tools,Android SDK Build-tools`[image]) which are in Tools folder.

Comment: Thanks!   That was it.   Why don't those things get installed automatically?

Comment: Android-sdk has been updated now, and these tools are newly added. Its like previous available tools, so its need to install manual.