# Android Support Library v7 R.id. Error

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have added the support library v7 to my project and I think it worked because ActionBarActivity is recognized (import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity works).
The problem is that for all my R.ids the R is underlined with the message R cannot be resolved to a variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably with R, not anything to do with the support library. Sometimes cleaning the project solves the problem.

A Google search with that message (*"R cannot be resolved to a variable"*) returns tons of answers, try those. Also Stackoverflow is full of these:

- ["R cannot be resolved to a variable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)
- [Eclipse error: R cannot be resolved to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642604/eclipse-error-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)
- [Eclipse giving error, missing R.java file after recent update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update?lq=1)

If it's got nothing to do with that, then maybe you've got an error in some XML file.