# Eclipse: "R cannot be resolved to a variable" in Android code

Tags: android

I have installed eclipse and followed steps by installing the install new software and setting up sdk as well. but error in MainActivity.java is  "R cannot be resolved to a variable". Please help me on this.

following is the code

```
package com.home.begingwithandroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

thanks

XML code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hellp"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/This is my first Android Application"/>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/And this is clickable button!"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: classic error... see these : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642604/eclipse-error-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating

Comment: I have watched all of them but nothing is working for me

Comment: try it correctly, it should work...

Comment: Its been six days, right from the start of the day till the end of the day. I try to fix this problem but still not been able to fix it. Please help

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); is the error on this line?

Comment: yes error is in this line

Comment: is there an import named - import android.R; or anything like this in your mainActivity? And what error shows on line - setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)?

Comment: I don't know what was the problem and what fixed it.

Comment: I just downloaded new eclipse and it worked for me. That's it.

Comment: Thanks for everybody's help.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your xml file

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hellp"/>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/This is my first Android Application"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/And this is clickable button!"/>
```

when using `@string/This is my first Android Application` it means you have a string named `This is my first Android Application` in your strings file. if you want to show that text exactly, just remove `@string` from it.

Comment: After importing. A new error is discovered 

The import com.home.begingwithandroid.R cannot be resolved

Please help?

Comment: then you have an error in your `xml` files. check error log to find problem.

Comment: Actually I am writing this xml file from a book. I have matched this xml code with the one in the book. But found no errors. I have updated question with this xml code as well. Please do let me know if there is some error. Thanks

Comment: Well, when I try to run the project it says:

Your project contains error(s) : please fix them before running the project. 


And there is no error in xml but R is not resolved at all.

Comment: Changed the xml code. But still says can not resolve R.