# R cannot be resolved to variable

Tags: android, xml

I have pulled my project from github and since then I got the issue “R cannot be resolved to a variable” . Also my folder inside res folder started appearing grey. Below is the screen shots. can anybody help me to solve this issue?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will an error in your res folder that is hindering the formation of R.java. See if there is any error in res and then clean the project.

Comment: Bro I have checked all my xmls , there was no update in any of the xml files whiled I pulled the project.The project was working fine till then. I have restarted my eclipse cleaned the project but still getting the same error.

Comment: see if your gen folder has R.java

Comment: Nopes it not generating R.java

Comment: it means there will be some error and some time eclipse don't show it.Clean your project and show in console check for error under problems tab

Answer (score 0):

What IDE do you use? However first of all check your AndroidManifestXml for errors. Check if paths are right. After that try to clean/build your project.
I hope to help you

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your ADT plugins because you imported example may its not suppoted..follow this it will give you idea [Eclipse error: R cannot be resolved to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642604/eclipse-error-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)