# Android: R cannot be resolved after adding design library in eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, r.java-file, android-design-library

I am working on eclipse. I have added design library in my project and after adding the library I'm getting this error i.e., R cannot be resolved to a variable.

I have applied every possible solution of this problem yet this is no result and change.

I have attached screenshot of my project. If anyone aware of this problem and knows the solution please do let me know.

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have to clean your project

Comment: Try restarting and sync first

Comment: Check your project or library drawable files having caps letter and also check every drawable files starts with small letters. If your xml file having error means you will get R file error. If everything is perfect then clean your project and rebuild your project. Try to switchover to Android Studio

Comment: I have already cleaned and Re-build the project @Ravi

Comment: @Manthan Thanks. I will check out all the file. Actually I am switching to Android Studio but the project is so big it will take time getting the same error in that to so.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642604/eclipse-error-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable/16643060#16643060

Comment: @AmitVaghela already done. Actually i have checked every possible solution. But didnt worked out. Thanks btw.