# Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project ,Path must include project and resource name

Tags: android

I am trying to clean project,each time it gives R error that is R can not be resolved to a variable,Please help to find this issue.

Comment: try to invalidate caches and then restart

Comment: how to invalidate caches,please

Comment: If using android studio, then click on file->Invalidate caches / restart

Comment: i am working this project in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Please check your res folder. If there is any syntax error(naming convention in drawables) in res than it gives R error.

Comment: res folder is correct.Project has no issue ,one day i had shut down system after restart of eclipse it is giving error.

Comment: Please refer this link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642604/eclipse-error-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable